# how to get Server machine "NT Authority\Network Service" account login name domain\machineName$ from window powershell command

Tags: sql-server, powershell, iis, local-system-account

I have 2 machine where IIS exist and another is SQL one, From IIS machine through powershell i want to add Network Service user to SQL Login, How to get "NT Authority\Network Service" account name like Domain\machineName$, is there a direct way or i have to get seperate Domain name and Machine name and combine them. Exact properties that i can use.

Comment: `NT Authority\Network Service` can't connect to another host as itself, its a local system account (as you've tagged). You'll need to run IIS under a domain account or use impersonation in your application to connect via Windows Authentication to a SQL instance on another host.

Comment: i believe it connect as domain\machineName$ to SQL if i set Network Service in Application pool user.

Comment: Do you have to use powershell command? you can try to enter Network Service and click on Check Names in Select Users or Groups.

Comment: Yes this i am doing in installer code while installing software as web application , and pool user as Network Service, i want to automatically give rights to that user in DB.